# Awk lines between values

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gawk

I have a similar infile:

```
1 And finally, monsieur, a wafer-thin mint.
2 Nah.
3 Oh, sir, it's only a tiny, little, thin one.
4 No. ****** off. I'm full.
5 Oh, sir. Hmm? It's only wafer thin.
6 Look. I couldn't eat another thing. I'm absolutely stuffed. Bugger off.
7 Oh, sir, just-- just one.
8 All right. Just one. 
9 Just the one, monsieur. Voilà.
```

command:

```
awk '$1 >1 && $1 < 4 || $1 > 5 && $1 < 8' infile
```

this should give me

```
2 Nah.
3 Oh, sir, it's only a tiny, little, thin one.
6 Look. I couldn't eat another thing. I'm absolutely stuffed. Bugger off.
7 Oh, sir, just-- just one.
```

So this example works. But this command:

```
awk '$1 > 10510000 && $1 < 12390000 || $1 < 2709520 || $1 > 57443438 || $1 > 20680000 && < 20930000'
```

gives me this:

```
awk: $1 > 10510000 && $1 < 12390000 || $1 < 2709520 || $1 > 57443438 || $1 > 20680000 && < 20930000
awk:                                                                                     ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Monty python. The meaning of life.

Comment: @AWE hahahahahaha you were waiting for that

Comment: which awk you are using?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using `GNU awk`?

Comment: I think I am using Gawk

Comment: Maybe there is another joke hidden in the answer, but it is working in my Ubuntu 12.10 :D I don't know how to get awk version.

Comment: It works for me with both gawk and mawk.  Have you checked for typos?

Comment: `awk --version` for gawk , `awk -W version` for mawk (for fedorqui)

Comment: Thanks, @abasu! It was mawk because it just worked the second way.

Comment: `awk: $1 > 10510000 && $1 < 12390000 || $1 < 2709520 || $1 > 57443438 || $1 > 20680000 && < 20930000
awk:                                                                                     ^ syntax error`

Comment: Your line should start with `awk '$1 >`, not `awk: '$1 >` (note not colon)

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7        It starts with `awk '$1 >` the error message puts the semicolon there

Comment: Make it simplier: does `awk '$1 >1 && $1 < 4' infile` work? Also, some brackets would help to make it more clear: `($1 >1 && $1 < 4) || ($1 > 5 && $1 < 8)`

Comment: i run the exact same thing in gawk 3.1.5, and it worked fine

Comment: Now I see the example works for me too but I pasted the real command that gave the error

Comment: For those whose awk worked with the posted script - get a new awk :-)!

Comment: @EdMorton Look at the first revision, only valid `awk` was posted originally, the second script was only added after all the comments.

Comment: @sudo_O - ah, i see. reads very differently now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted script has a syntax error at the position indicated by the error message:

```
awk: $1 > 10510000 && ... || $1 > 20680000 && < 20930000
awk:                                          ^ syntax error
```

because you have `&& < 20930000` instead of `&& $1 < 20930000`, assuming it's $1 you want to compare.

Comment: Yes I missed two symbols. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your second script is missing an operand exactly where the error message points too:

```
... || $1 > 20680000 && < 20930000
awk:                    ^ syntax error
```

This should be:

```
... || $1 > 20680000 && $1 < 20930000
```